# Does SoundEffect.CreateInstance load from file everytime?

Tags: xna, c#, audio

This is something which has been bugging me. If I create a SoundEffectInstance via  SoundEffect.CreateInstance() I'm meant to dispose of it when I'm finished with it. SoundEffect.CreateInstance() does not use ContentManager as far as i can tell.

So does it load from file or does it keep a copy in memory? Loading from file would obviously be very slow :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an **implementation detail**. You don't know for sure, it doesn't matter, it might differ between platforms, and it might change in the future.

However you can make an educated guess: First of all the fact that `SoundEffectInstance` exists, and that you load sound files into `SoundEffect` indicates that `SoundEffect` is probably responsible for holding the sound effect in memory. And the existence of `SoundEffect.FromStream` and the buffer-based `SoundEffect` constructors are strong indications that `SoundEffect` *must* have a mechanism for keeping a sound buffer in memory. Therefore it is fairly safe to assume that when you load a `SoundEffect` from a file, it uses the same mechanism.

If it's really important, you could test it by deleting or modifying the sound file, after loading the `SoundEffect`, and then creating an instance.

As always, if performance is really important, you should *measure it*.

Of course, creating a `SoundEffectInstance` does allocate resources (audio voices, managed and probably unmanaged memory). So it's not something that you should be creating regularly if you can avoid it - such as by pooling and reusing instances. When you're using `SoundEffect.Play`, then `SoundEffect` is internally managing a pool of `SoundEffectInstance` objects for you.